# How to set security at Parameter level in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report which will have Parameter **ClientName** and i have 3 clients in the drop down,so my requirement is users for the particular client has to view only their client name without displaying the other Client names .Is it possible to do so?can i impose any security to users at parameter level?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this before isn't elegant, but it did work.

Create a parameter table in my DB and mapped the windows user ids to which parameters should be available to that user, like

```
User               Clientname
----------------------------
domain\jdoe        Company1
domain\mjones      Company2
domain\jdoe        Company3
```

Use the Global SSRS function "UserID" to get the current user who is accessing the report.

Pass the UserID as a parameter to a query that will populate your dropdown prior to runtime, like

```
Select Clientname from table where user like '@Userid'
```

That way only the Clientnames associated with the user viewing the report are visible in the parameter dropdown box.

However, this is annoying to maintain with more than a handful of users and doesn't support ActiveDirectory Groups, as far as I can tell.